# Firestore get document where subcollection exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It this possible to do? After some research, I couldn't find a way to do it.

My "workaround" is to get all subCollection documents first, then retrieve their parent keys and retrieve again. But I believe there is a better way to do it.

```
let subDocs = await firestoreDb.collectionGroup('sub_collections').get()
let parentDocKeys = {};
subDocs.docs.forEach(async (element) => {
    parentDocKeys[element.ref.parent.parent.id] = 1;
});
let result = await firestoreDb.collection('parentCollection').where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', Object.keys(parentDocKeys)).get();
return res.send(result.docs.map(x=>x.data()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Firestore queries can only filter documents based on data in the document itself. There is no way to check data in any other documents, neither in the same collection, nor in other (sub)collections.

This means that it is not possible to retrieve only documents for which a subcollection exists without changing the data in the parent document. For example, if you update a field (say `hasSubcollectionBla`) in the parent document each time you add/remove to the subcollection, you can filter on the value of that field.

What you do with this is making the writing of data more complex, so that the read/query becomes easier and more scalable. This is a common trade-off when using NoSQL databases, such as Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination and the suggestion! One more question here... Is it proper to use firestore trigger for that? Just a bit worried that if I have multiple sub collection for that document, then I will have to maintain hasSubCollection1/2/3... with corrosponding firestore trigger here.

Comment: If you want to just check if a document has any subcollections then the "hasSubcollection: true" field will work just fine. Anytime you added an extra subcollection and you update the parent document to have that field it will just re-write that value to true. If you need to check to see if a document has a specific subcollection then you would have to have something like the hasSubcollection 1/2/3 you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, this could be perfectly done in a Cloud Function, but also in client-side code - for example with a batched write while adding/removing to the subcollection. Having multiple flag field does not strike me as a problem: you can fit quite a few flags within the 1MB document limit. :)